# WPF: Is there a way to save the image in the Viewport3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, viewport3d

I have some 3d points I have to plot and since as far as I know there isn't a chart library for C# that will do this easily, I thought the next easier way to do it would be to create the points in a viewport3d and save the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do charts, you might want to consider just using a WPF chart control, such as [Visifire](http://visifire.codeplex.com/).

Otherwise, you can use a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render the Viewport.